# How to get data from database using hibernate template

Tags: java, hibernate

- Hi,  Is it possible how to get data database tables ,column names and column
  values etc ?

I have tried sample snippet code please let me know how to get    database column names and values ?

```
public List<String> getAllTables(){
    Map<String, ClassMetadata> classMetaDataMap =
    hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
    for(Map.Entry<String, ClassMetadata> metaDataMap : classMetaDataMap.entrySet()) {
        ClassMetadata classMetadata = metaDataMap.getValue();
        AbstractEntityPersister abstractEntityPersister = (AbstractEntityPersister) classMetadata;
        String tableName = abstractEntityPersister.getTableName();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(AppTaskConfig.class);
String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();` Use these code for getting column names

Comment: property names showing pojo class variables ? I need to display database column name or pojo class annotation column name ?

Comment: @sameer `String[] columnNames = abstractEntityPersister.getKeyColumnNames();`

Comment: I added as an answer

Comment: for Property values I have tried but Illegal Argument Error please let me know  correct way to get property values based on property names ?`Object[] propertyvalue =abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValues(ExportReport.class,EntityMode.POJO);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hibernate for getting column names use the following:

```
ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Person.class); 
String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
```

And for getting column values you can use Hibernate Criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
List list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: I'm using hibernate template how could I make it session .sorry for asking.`private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
  @Autowired
 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
   hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
 }`

Comment: No problem. You can check for everything about hibernate from these tutorials. 1.https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html 2.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/

Comment: one more I have getting separate constraint column name as a database column name and Pojo class declare variables ? Is it possible to make all in single list ? Example constraint column name : `String Id = abstractEntityPersister.getIdentifierPropertyName();
           String[] columns = abstractEntityPersister.getPropertyColumnNames(Id);String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();`

Comment: thanks for it .finally I done like to get list column values, but how could make it single column names ? I mean I'm getting separate constraint column name and pojo class variables ?`List<ExportReport> listcriteria =hibernateTemplate.findByExample(classobj);`

Comment: Actually I'm trying to write data to excel file , so I need to get column values based on column names is there any alternate solution ?